# How to filter a date range in a cubeset function?

Tags: excel, mdx, olap, mdx-query, cubefunctions

I want to implement a filter in a cubeset function to get the values only for a limited time period, e.g. 2 weeks. However, I struggle with the syntax of the filter function.

Getting the values in a cubevalue function works for the selected time period, but not in the cubeset function. Defining the cubeset function only by listing the time periods is also not an option, since it then gives you an additional column with the week nr, but what I need is to have the values in an aggregated form at the end.

The result of the cubeset will then be retrieved by a cuberankedmember function to have a ranking, and finally the cubevalue function delivers the values.

```
=CUBESET("Datamodel", "Filter( {[Contribution Flight].[Flt CarrierNo].&["&Overview!$B$17&"], [Allotment].[Allotment].&[n] , [Origin].[Origin Code].children} , {[Dep Date Itinerary].[Dep Date Itin Week].["&Overview!AN7&"],[Dep Date Itinerary].[Dep Date Itin Week].["&Overview!AM7&"]})")
```

The outcome should be the volumes by origin codes, for the above determined period of 2 weeks.